# Is there a way to use the handy clay render button in 2.79. But exept elements from this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, lighting

I want to render a room in clay.

But also want to use an emission object in the scene, to light the scene.

Is there a quick way to do this?

Besides giving all things a clay material and expecting the emission object there.